# Set onClick function without firing said function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have an a-html-element which has a onclick function

```
   <a id="tourTrigger" onclick="javascript:tourfunction()"/>
```

Now during the time where the function is executed I want to disable the link so I do this in my function:

```
    document.getElementById("tourTrigger").onclick = null;
```

Now when my function is finished i want to set the onclick on its initial value:

```
    document.getElementById("tourTrigger").onclick = tourfunction();
```

My problem with this solution is that tourfunction() is fired at this place so i create an endless loop.

Anybody got any ideas? JQuery also is fine.
Thanks for your help

Comment: `document.getElementById("tourTrigger").onclick = tourfunction;` ?

Comment: Assign a handler reference, not an invocation

Comment: document.getElementById("tourTrigger").onclick = "tourfunction()"; ?

Comment: `javascript:` is unnecessary.

Comment: `document.getElementById("tourTrigger").addEventListener('click', tourfunction, false);` would be the correct  approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't invoke the function:

```
 document.getElementById("tourTrigger").onclick = tourfunction;
```

But I would advice to use `addEventListener` instead:

```
document.getElementById("tourTrigger").addEventListener('cli‌​ck', tourfunction);
```

since the latter allows to add multiple callbacks.

Comment: How can i pass parameters to the function without instantly calling it as well?